# Differences between testing iOS app on iPhone and iPod

Tags: iphone, ios, ipod

I am developing a application that would not use any phone functionality.  But it requires internet connection.
Would it be sufficient if I test the application on iPod and not on iPhone?
Mostly RetinaDisplay.

Comment: Why wouldn't the iPod be sufficient?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a newer iPod touch with a retina display then yes, it should be just fine.  If not you may want to test also test it on a device with a retina display.  But in general it is a good idea to test your apps on multiple devices.